# Top Navigation Dropdown menu inconsistent Sub-Site display

Tags: 2013, navigation, sub-site

I'm working on leveling out our intranet and ran into a situation. Our dropdown menu isn't showing the Sub-Sites for our committee page. The following is how the dropdown currently works:

```
About Us                 (Folder, linked to a subsite)
   Principles            (Page)
   Organization Chart    (Page
   Annual Reports        (External link)
   Committees            (1st level subsite)
```

And it should be showing something more like this:

```
About Us                 (Folder, linked to subsite)
   Principles            (Page)
   Organization Chart    (Page
   Annual Reports        (External link)
   Committees            (1st level subsite)
      Committee 1        (2nd level subsite)
      ...                (2nd level subsite)
      Committee n        (2nd level subsite)
```

The indents indicate a dropdown/flyout menu.

Some info:

1. Using SharePoint 2013
2. Using Structural Nav (with Show subsite checked)
3. Using my admin account, therefore permissions shouldn't be an issue
4. It doesn't matter if the folder object has a URL attached or not.
5. The 2nd level pages don't show anywhere for this specific subsite, but they do for other 1st level sites.

For example we have a dropdown setup as...

```
Toolbox                  (Folder, no link to subsite)
   References            (1st level subsite)
      Reference Site 1   (2nd level subsite)
      ...                (2nd level subsite)
      Reference Site n   (2nd level subsite)
   Tools                 (1st level subsite)
      Brand Centre       (2nd level subsite)
      Forms              (2nd level subsite)
```

and it works as expected.

**Is there some setting or functionality I'm unaware of that allows some first level subsites to show their subsites, but not others?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why it works this way, but I found out that folders and subsites don't like to show for our environment as dropdown children, but it does for regular 'links'.

Example: if on the Committee page I have the following Current Nav setup

```
Home           (Folder)
Recent         (Folder)
   Members     (Link)
   Events      (Link)
Committee 1    (Subsite 1)
Committee 2    (Subsite 2)
Committee 3    (link)
```

Then I get the following as my top navigation:

```
About Us                 (Folder, linked to subsite)
   Principles            (Page)
   Organization Chart    (Page
   Annual Reports        (External link)
   Committees            (1st level subsite)
      Committee 3        (2nd level subsite)
```

Which does not have Committee 1 or 2, which were set as 'subsite' links and not a regular 'link' when going through the Site Settings -> Navigation -> Current Navigation

Comment: The "Show Subsites" and "Show Pages" options in the navigation settings are present in each sub site. Have you checked the sub sites to see if they have the appropriate boxes checked?

Comment: Yes they were checked.

Comment: Do you have structured nav set for both top nav and current nav? Are all of the publishing pages at the root level of their respective Pages libraries in their respective sub sites? What do you mean by folder in your navigation description? You can have pages, sites and links in your nav. You can't link to a folder unless you set up a manual link that points to a folder in a document library. Structural navigation reads the site structure, but it doesn't play well with folders in the Pages library. The sub site should stand in for the folder when organizing pages in a larger site.

Comment: I have answered my own question. And I suppose by folder I mean 'Heading' in the structural navigation. It's a linkable header (choose to have it direct to a url or not) that can have links, pages, and subsites one level underneath it.